# Is it a correct way to loop through the NSURL to download the images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I have various image size files loaded on each URL and would like to download the data at the same time without using multiple calls to each URL. I am trying to loop through the URL using a variable and storing the data. Is it the correct way of doing it ?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code.

    isImageRequested = NO;
}
return self;
}

-(BOOL) isImageRequested
{
   return isImageRequested;
}


-(void) startImageDownloading
{

if (!isImageRequested)
{
    isImageRequested = YES;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {

        NSLog(@"Inside for loop");
        URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.abc.com/method=image&size=%d", i];  
        //NSLog(@"string : %d", URLString);
        self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
        NSURLRequest *pServerRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];
        self.serverConnection= [[[NSURLConnection alloc] 
                                 initWithRequest:pServerRequest delegate:self] autorelease];

              /*UPDATED*/
                    if (i == 1) {

            prefixString = @"image_124_";
        }

        if (i == 2) {

            prefixString = @"image_250_";
        }

        if (i == 3) {

            prefixString = @"image_500_";
        }

        if (i == 4) {

            prefixString = @"image_750_";
        }

        if (i == 5) {

            prefixString = @"image_1000_";
        }

        if (i == 6) {

            prefixString = @"image_1500_";
        }

        if (i == 7) {

            prefixString = @"image_2000_";
        }


    }
   }

}



 -(void)cancelConnectionRequest
  {
    if (isImageRequested && serverConnection != nil)
    {
    [self.serverConnection cancel];self.serverConnection = nil;
    [self removeActivityIndicator];
    [self deallocateResources];
    isImageRequested = NO;
   }

  }

  - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:           (NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge 
    {
      if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod  isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
{
    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
[challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}


 -(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)   response 
   {
     [responseData setLength:0]; 

    }


 -(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *) data 
  {
    [responseData appendData:data];

   }

   -(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *) error 
    {
NSLog(@"Error occured while loading image : %@",error);
[self removeActivityIndicator];
[self deallocateResources];


UILabel *tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 30)];
[tempLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[tempLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0f]];
[tempLabel setCenter:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2)];
[tempLabel setText:@"Image not available."];
[self addSubview:tempLabel];
[tempLabel release];

 }


-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection 
 {


UIImage *tempImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:responseData];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithData:responseData]);

self.image = tempImage;

      /*UPDATED*/
     PhotoViewController *photoMap = [[PhotoViewController alloc] init] ;


 [photoMap saveTilesOfSize:(CGSize){500,500} forImage:tempImage toDirectory:directoryPath usingPrefix:prefixString]; 
[tempImage release];


}

   -(void) deallocateResources
  {

if (serverConnection != nil) 
{
    [serverConnection release];
    serverConnection = nil;
}
if (responseData != nil)
{
    [responseData release];
    responseData = nil;
     }

   }


 - (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
[responseData release];
[serverConnection release];
 }


 @end
```

Comment: I guess the question is, is it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you get your photos depends on what the server you connect to allows.

It could have a specific URL where you can download a bunch of photos, or you could be forced doing it like you are doing now. Which is fully correct as an approach if the server does not allow to do anything fancier.

So, it depends on the API of your service.

On the other hand, if you don't want to initiate multiple request at the same time, you could use an `NSOperationQueue` to serialize you network operations.

Comment: But the line [responseData appendData:data]; appends the data each time you loop through it. Can I give any naming convention so that it knows which size the image is and append to that data?

Comment: I don't understand completely your comment. If you would like to make your life easier with that, you could use ASIHTTPRequest instead of NSURLRequest. It is here: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: I have updated my code above. I am trying to store the images with size = 1 to 7 and name each tile images a different name. But the naming starts when the loop is over and uses the last value which is "image_2000_".

Comment: again, I hope I interpret correctly your comment. The place where you know which request is being processed is `connection:didReceiveResponse` so you should try to do something there to get the names right (indeed `NSURLResponse` contains the URL so you can get the name from that).

Comment: I actually have to assign the names at each loop stage like for the 1st count, the string name : image_124 has to be assigned as a prefix for future use. is there a way you can do that ?

Comment: The only way I see is in `connection:didReceiveResponse` set a class variable to the current image name (derived from the URL); then store the data you get under that name. But really, is you decide to use ASIHTTPRequest (which is really simple to use), this will be done in a snap, because each individual request has got its own delegate, so you will know for sure the name; furthermore, the data will be passed to you in a single call.

Comment: I really apologize since I have not tried it, is it possible for you to give me an example on how to store the data in connection:didReceiveResponse under that class name?

Comment: In `connection:didReceiveResponse`, I would simply store in a variable a suitable name for your image; you can derive it from the URL. Then, in `connectionDidFinishLoading`, where you build your NSImage from NSData, you read that variable to save the image to a file. I cannot go in more detail that this now.

Comment: Sergio: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I did call a suitable name for each image and called the NSURLConnection for each image assigned.